# How to access PostgreSQL with Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, postgresql, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, ironpython

I create hangman game with silverlight ironpython and I use data in postgresql for random word but I don't know to access data in postgresql in silverlight.
how can or should it be done?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

From Silverlight you cannot access a database directly (remember it's a web technology that actually runs locally on the client and the client cannot access your database directly over the internet).

To communicate with the server from Silverlight, you must create a separated WebService either with SOAP, WCF or RIA Services for example.

That Webservice will expose your data on the web.  Call the WebService method to get your data from your Silverlight program.

This WebService layer will be your middle tiers that actually makes the bridge between your postgresql database and your Silverlight application.